# Simplifying code with multiple loops and logic, into queryset aggregates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

My models:

```
class customer(models.Model):
    cstid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    insurance_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    ageyrs = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

class Admission(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    diagnosis = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='', blank=True)
    date_admission = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ward = models.ForeignKey(Ward, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bed = models.ForeignKey(Bed, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    discharged = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ip_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    ip_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', blank=True)
```

My objective: Set a variable to a query filter, adding a property, 'is_admitted' to the queryset, so that I can pass this query set to the template and use the property while displaying data.

Code:

```
def is_admitted(cust):
    admission = Admission.objects.filter(customer=cust, discharged=False)
    admission_results = len(admission)
    if admission_results > 0:
        return True
    return False


my_q = or_q_if_truthfull(
    cstid=HospitalID,
    name__lower__contains=name.lower() if name else None,
    ageyrs=ageyrs if ageyrs.isdigit() else None,
    agemnths=agemnths if agemnths.isdigit() else None,
    mobile__contains=mobile if mobile else None,
    alternate__contains=alternate if alternate else None,
    email__lower__contains=email.lower() if email else None,
    address__lower__contains=address.lower() if address else None,
    city__lower__contains=city.lower() if city else None
)
ORSearchResult = customer.objects.filter(my_q, linkedclinic=clinicobj)
cust_set = []
cust_admission_status = []
for cust in ORSearchResult:
    cust_set.append(cust)
    cust_admission_status.append(is_admitted(cust))
    print(f"Customer name: {cust.name} Admission status: {is_admitted(cust)}")
cust_templ_set = zip(cust_set, cust_admission_status)
```

And in template, I will do:

```
{% for cust, status in cust_templ_set %}
    {{ cust.name }} {{ status }}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to understand how I can convert my above code by generating an aggregate over the queryset, so that I can use a property of the query, and change the template code to the following, and avoid the loop in the view, and the zip. So that the template code becomes:

```
{% for cust in customers %}
    {{ cust.name }} {{ cust.is_admitted }}
{% endfor %}
```

I am not sure whether I am making complete sense, and can explain further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use [conditional-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) together with [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate). It could look like this:

```
from django.db import models

qs = Customer.objects.filter(...)    # your filter conditions go here

# now add a field to the resulting queryset
qs = qs.annotate(
    active_admissions=models.Count(
        models.Case(
            models.When(admission__discharged=False, then=1),
            output_field=models.IntegerField())))
```

Now each object in the queryset will have an additional attribute called `active_admissions` which will contain the number of active admissions.
This could be used in the template like this:

```
{% for cust in qs %}
    {{ cust.name }} {{ cust.active_admissions }}
{% endfor %}
```

Maybe you need to modify the subquery to fit your specific needs. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood you right, perhaps you might want this:

```
cust = customer.objects.filter(my_q, linkedclinic=clinicobj)
is_admitted_sub_q = Admission.objects.filter(customer=OuterRef('pk'), discharged=False)
cust_templ_set = cust.annotate(is_admitted=Exists(is_admitted_sub_q), )
```

this will return a list of customers with additional field `is_admitted` which will be `True` if there exists at least one linked (to this customer) record in `Admission`.

[OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef), [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries)